# why is my XOR program not working on Windows when XORing executables

Tags: c, windows, bitwise-xor

I wrote an XOR program in C. The purpose of the program is to XOR files, I have tested this program on Linux as it is my main OS and it worked perfectly with an '.exe' (I was using wine to execute exe's on Linux). When the program was tested on Windows however, I noticed that I was losing bytes of data when I XORed the file and I do not know why, if somebody can shed some light on the situation it would be really appreciated. Below I have posted the code to my XOR program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//XOR key
#define XOR_KEY 0x6F

void XORFile(char *infile, char *outfile)
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    int rlen;
    char buf[4096];

    fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    fp2 = fopen(outfile, "w");

    while (1) {
        rlen = fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fp);
        if (rlen <= 0)
            break;

        // XOR read file buffer
        for (int i = 0; i < rlen;  ++i)
            buf[i] ^= XOR_KEY;

        fwrite(buf,1,rlen,fp2);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc <= 3){
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [CRYPT] [IN FILE] [OUTFILE]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    XORFile (argv[2], argv[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the `"rb"/"wb"` mode for binary files.

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate, I am new to C also I am confused as the executable could be XORed on Linux and XORed again to its original state and still execute so why would the same not apply to Windows?

Comment: Windows is handling text files differently than binary, and should be explicitly told what kind of handling to do. It is different from Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you should use the `"rb"` and `"wb"` modes in your `fopen` calls (the added `b` opens/creates the file in *binary* mode).

In *text* mode (the default), Windows does some special processing on certain characters (like converting between a single `\n` and the `\r\n` pair).

From [cppreference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> Text files are files containing sequences of lines of text. Depending
>   on the environment where the application runs, some special character
>   conversion may occur in input/output operations in text mode to adapt
>   them to a system-specific text file format. Although on some
>   environments no conversions occur and both text files and binary files
>   are treated the same way, using the appropriate mode improves
>   portability.